# how to add wait in framework in selenium

Tags: selenium

this is my test:

```
public void Add_Store()
        {
            StepDescription = " Create a Store";

            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            Store_Link.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            Create_Store_Button.Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32("5000"));

}
```

I want to remove all the sleep; where should i add the wait now? i want to make it generic; so it make sense to add in the element locator itself?

the element locator looks as below:

```
[Find(ControlType = ElementType.Hyperlink, Properties = "XPath=//a[starts-with(@id, 'Stores')]")]

private Element Store_Link { get; set; }
```

since i want to make the wait generic, can you guide me how to remove the sleep and add the wait?

Comment: What framework and code is that? It looks nothing like python as your question is tagged. It looks like C#.

Comment: @JeffC sorry this is c#; python got added after i accepted the edit; let me remove this; sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Explicit wait instead of sleep,

**Python:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ""))).click()

//EC.presence_of_element_located
//EC.element_to_be_clickable
```

**C#:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webElement)).Click();
```

There are many types of wait.

One of the best Solution for creating JS wait Framework for project:

Blog Link : https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/

& Github link : https://github.com/swtestacademy/JSWaiter

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How are links to references in Java supposed to help OP who is asking about python?

Comment: It looks like you both didn't understand what I meant to my answer.  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ""))).click() Is this look Java ? Provided JS framework to build for Project.

Comment: sorry for mentioning python...some one gave a edit and i have accepted; i think the python was added after the edit

Comment: @kavitha I have added reference for C#,

Comment: Thanks @IshitaShah ; let me try; but overall, i have around 250 scripts and follow a simple page object framework; in that case, i dont want to add wait for all the scripts; is it possible add in one or two generic place instead of adding in all the scripts?

Comment: @kavitha Yes, It is possible. You can define Page load wait by defining in single method and You have to just call it. I am using this way in my own project. Please refer updated answer.

Comment: Thankyou @IshitaShah ; this is what i was looking for; let me try ; thanks a lot in taking your time and helping me out

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged **Python** :

You can use `explicit wait` as **@Ishita** has mentioned. Though you want to have generic wait , that can be used every where.

For generic, you may create instance of WebDriverWait in setup/fixtures level.Something like :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(webDriverInstance, timeInSec)  
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'Some id')))
```

or may be somewhere else in your code :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'Some id')))
```

Now you can use this wait reference, in your code where ever it has the **accessibility**.

For Reference, you can use this link [Selenium_explicit_wait_Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

and the code you have shared look likes in **C#** :

You can use this **code** in this case :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));
```

Note that we can bind **conditions** with **EC** (**ExpectedConditions**).

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for taking time and replying; let me try this; python got added by mistake; this is in c#

Comment: @kavitha : I have given code in C# also , try it you may be able to resolve your issue.